# How to change visibility in dynamically generated content Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Hi Everyone so here's the problem, I think it's mostly a little problem with my lack of knowledge in Javascript but here's what I did:

JS Code:

```
function mostrarResul(idFold, Id)
{

    if($(idFold).css(visibility) == "none")
    {
        $(idFold).css(visibility, inline);
        $(Id).detach();
        $(Id).append("<a id='"+Id+"' class='showmore' onclick='mostrarResul("+idFold+", "+Id+")'>ver menos</a>");
    }else
    {
        $(idFold).css(visibility, none);
        $(Id).detach();
        $(Id).append("<a id='"+Id+"' class='showmore' onclick='mostrarResul("+idFold+", "+Id+")'>ver m&aacute;s</a>");
    }

}
```

PHP Code:

```
$idFolder = $item[_folder_name];
                    $idFolder = strtolower($idFolder);
                    $idFolder = str_replace(" ", "_", $idFolder);
                    echo "<div class='result'>";
                    echo "<div class='item'>
                    <label><a onclick='mostrarResul($idFolder, $id)'>".$item[_folder_name]."</a></label>";
                    $news = process_all("SELECT * FROM _tips WHERE _folder = '$item[_folder_name]' ORDER BY _date_create LIMIT 0,20");
                    echo "<div class='itemNews' id='".$idFolder."' style='display:none'>";
                    echo "<ul>";
                    if ($news) foreach( $news as $n)
                    {
                        echo "<a href='/consejos-recomendaciones/".$n[_permalink]."'>".$n[_subject]."</a><br/>";
                    }
                    echo "</ul";
                    echo "</div>";
                    echo "<a id='".$id."' class='showmore' onclick='mostrarResul($idFolder, $id)'>ver m&aacute;s</a>
                    </div>";
                    echo "</div>";
                    $id += 1;
```

Ok so the JS code is supposed to change the visibility attribute depending on it's current state and detach & append code depending on the same things, my real problem is when sending the variables to the JS and manipulating them, any tips??

Hi again, Someone said before that I could do this using Jquery.js and I wanted to ask how???, I'm already using jquery for other things and wanted to now how to use it when I'm creating the Id for the tags???

Solved.
The other thing is, do you guys now what function in PHP 5.2 returns a string of a length that I want, example

String Val= "Hello everyone";

(function to manipulate string)

and the new string val is "Hello".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your problem (that I see) is that everything inside .css() should be in quotes. I assume you're using jQuery? If not already, you need to include it in your page head, like this:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then everything you write in jQuery should not be without quotes:

```
 $(idFold).css(visibility, inline);
```

but should be like this:

```
 $(idFold).css('visibility', 'inline');
```

Also, the hidden property not "none" is the correct property for visibility

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp has more info on it.

Comment: OK I did what you told me but I have a little problem, it still won't function I have checked the Firefox error console and it says: "admin0 is not defined". admin0 is one of the idFold that is generated

Comment: I don't now but am I passing the variables the right way???? I mean in this function "mostrarResul($idFolder, $id)"

Comment: so I would replace 'none' with 'hidden' as 'none' is only valid for the 'display' property, not 'visibility'. On passing the variables, what are you actually sending into the js function? They need to be strings. Another problem I just noticed is that you need to change the way you're recursing the onclick events.

Comment: onclick='mostrarResul("+idFold+", "+Id+")'

should instead be:
    onclick='mostrarResul(idFold,Id)'

You are inserting the values of those variables, not the string 'Id', which is what this code is doing. You only need to put quotes around LITERAL things you're outputting. The variables inside the onclick need to be only the variable name without quotes. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your last question is substr. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
So in your case, it would be

```
$var = "Hello everyone";
$new_var = substr($var, 0, 5);
echo $var . ' - ' . $new_var;
```

Output would be: Hello everyone - Hello

Comment: Yes this would help me a lot with it, i didn't remember the function. thanks